# Close footer by clicking anywhere on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a question concerning collapsing/expanding a footer. I have a simple basic collapse/expand script going, where when the "Open" button is clicked, the hidden footer slides up and when you click "Close" it slides back down and hides again. Now, I want to attach an instance where I can click anywhere on teh DOM when the footer is open and it will close.

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#footerOpen").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#footerPanel").slideDown("slow");

    });

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#footerClose").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#footerPanel").slideUp("slow");
    });

    // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Anywhere if click isn't handled by another control? (for example a link?) In that case you can attach to body itself otherwise AFAIK you have to put a static transparent div on the top of your page and handle click there.

Comment: `$(document)` instead of `$("#footerOpen")` and `$("#footerClose")`

Comment: what should happen if you click inside `footerPanel` should it close then also

Comment: Hey Arun, I would prefer nothing happening when clicking inside the footerPanel. Tried but didn't come out with anything fruitful.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aUU9X/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#footerOpen").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#footerPanel").slideDown("slow");

    });

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#footerClose").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#footerPanel").slideUp("slow");
    });

    // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });

       //  click anywhere on teh DOM when the footer is open and it will close.
    $("body:not(#footerClose)").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div#footerPanel").slideUp("slow");
    });



});
```

try this one, im using jquery not selector.

Comment: Thanks Arkaprava. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click handler to the `document`, and do the `slideUp` in there. You can use the `event.target` to determine whether or not to perform the `slideUp`:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {

    // Don't slideUp if #footerOpen or #footerPanel are clicked
    if ($(e.target).is('#footerOpen, #footerPanel')) {
        return;
    }

    // Do the slideUp!
    $('#footerPanel').slideUp('slow'); 

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/z2VLM/6/)

If you have other elements within your `#footerPanel`, the above probably won't work as the target will likely be something other than `#footerPanel`, the best thing to do would be to add a `click` handler to `#footerPanel`, and prevent the event from propagating and triggering the above `click` handler:

```
$('#footerPanel').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/z2VLM/8/)

Comment: Thanx Billyonecan. It worked perfectly. Not to be a nuisance, I had a toggle going on dependent on state of teh footer. when the footer is collapsed, Open footer is displayed, and when the footer is expanded, "Close footer" is displayed. How can I implement that on this fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me...

```
 $(document).click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if(!$target.is("#footerPanel")){
         $("#footerPanel").slideUp('slow'); 
    }
 });
```